# Command to know active running kernel packages

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel

I have been doing some research and as far as I know, it's possible to have multiple versions of kernel and other kernel packages and to know the version of the active running kernel, the uname command can be used. But how about the other kernel packages like kernel-devel? I have listed some of my questions below.

1. When the kernel is installed or updated, does the other kernel packages like kernel-devel or kernel-headers also installed or updated with the same version like the kernel?
2. If multiple versions of kernel packages exists like the kernel-devel, does the latest version automatically becomes the active or running version? If not, is there a way to know what version is active or running?

Thank you in advance.

@schaiba Yes you're right, I was also referring to "running" when I have said active. On number 2., is this also the behavior with the other kernel packages? in which also the newest kernel-* packages will be use after a reboot?

In addition, I was referring to Red Hat distribution.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, once the kernel is updated, all kernel-* packages are updated as well.
2. Upon installation of a new kernel, GRUB is automatically updated to reflect the change and after reboot you will use the newest kernel. Like you said, you can use `uname -r` to see what version you are running. Also, I'm assuming by "active" you mean the same thing as "running". If not, please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

1) It depends on the Linux distribution.

2) Each version of the kernel has its kernel module directory under `/lib/modules`. To go in the **current** directory try:

```
cd /lib/modules/`uname -r`
```